# Hide "duplicate content" from Google after using mod_rewrite to remove .php file extension

Tags: mod-rewrite

Sorry for the somewhat cryptic title! I'll try to explain. I have the following in my .htacess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

So users can type `domain.com/foo/bar` and `domain.com/foo/bar.php` is served. Of course, typing `domain.com/foo/bar.php` also loads the same page.

So, in Google Webmaster Tools (under HTML Suggestions), Google thinks that i have duplicated all my meta descriptions and title tags as it sees bar and bar.php as two different files. I am worried Google will penalise this "duplicate content". What should i do? I am sure im not the first one to have this issue, but i am struggling to find related questions/answers.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer i used (as per my original comment) [from here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4067156.htm) which solved my problem

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+\.)+php?\ 
HTTP RewriteRule (.+)\.php?$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*/)*[^/.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: This is nice but what if google have already indexed my .php files? should I block them with robots.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Use [[R] (the redirect flag)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r).

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [R,L]
```

This forces an external redirect, so users who attempt to access domain.com/foo/bar.php will be redirected (through HTTP 302 Found) to domain.com/foo/bar. You'll also want to use [L] (last rule), so that the redirect happens immediately.

Comment: Hmm. I tried this and all requests to foo/bar were redirected to foo/bar.php (kinda the opposite of what i want!) I found this (http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4067156.htm) and the following code seems to work well:
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+\.)+php?\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.+)\.php?$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*/)*[^/.]+)$ /$1.php [L]`